# Why don't people just stop developing sites to cater to IE6?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, web-standards

I don't understand why developers continue to program things to accommodate IE6. People should update the browser they use, right?

I've already seen many firms completely stop developing for IE6, with a big article on their front page stating their update recommendations.

What are **your** reasons to continue developing for this buggy old dinosaur? If you say you must for your work, state why your organization continues to develop for IE6.

Of course, a community wiki, just because I'd like to see some reasons (if any).

Answer (score 16):

Because the users pay my bills.

I've worked in systems where **75%** of them used this browser. It sucks? Yes. But as every job, you have to address these issues.

If you can afford to lose 75% of your users, good luck.

Comment: But would you actually lose all IE6 users if your site didn't look quite the same in their browser?

Comment: "Quite the same" is subjective. Do you think having a website for your product/clients/brand that looks plain "wrong" for 75% of users is acceptable? If problems with IE6 were only with CSS or simple layout problems, I wouldn't even blame IE6. But sometimes you have legacy applications that answering "use jQuery" just doesn't work, you have 10000 lines of javascript written with "good old javascript", all coupled in a lot of complicated html stuff: if your javascript doesn't work, you don't have a broken layout, you have a broken application.

Comment: +1 for hitting the nail on the head.  In all cases we support IE6 because the customer requests IE6 support.

Answer (score 11):

We develop for IE6 because it specifically says in our contract that we only have to deliver code that works on it.

It sucks in many ways, as it's a terrible browser and it forces users of the system to stay with it, but...

Testing is easier, if it works in IE6 it works!

Comment: Hahahaha, +1 for your last comment. :P

Comment: You will be able to do a better job for your customers if you understand **why** they insist on IE6 support. They presumably pay the money that pays your salary: the better you know their needs, the better you can meet them, and then they will stick with you rather than some other contractor (which might lose you your job).

Answer (score 6):

One word `Corporations`, they have IE6 as their GO-TO browser, only now are they SLOWLYYY transitioning into IE8 (most skipped IE7).

I can clearly say, for my company (5000+ employees, located in over 15 counties), that they are just NOW getting IE8 setup for users, I have been a 'beta' tested internally for my company for months now :P

Comment: This is the case where I work. Current corporate build of Windows everyone is running is Windows XP with Internet Explorer 6. I think the only way the browser is going to get upgraded is when they upgrade to Windows 7 in the next 3 - 5 years. At least they are smart enough to skip Vista! Many internal apps still rely on IE6, so upgrading IE is not currently an option. Luckily as a developer I am "allowed" to install FireFox.

Comment: And this is the only real reason IE6 is still around. Eliminate corporate use and you'd see statistics drop on it to almost zero.

Comment: See funny thing is, I am `allowed` to install Firefox @ the office, but the corporate bluecoat (pos gatekeeper that analyzes traffic blocks firefox requests, so i HAVE to use IE for external sites).

Comment: Certainly you can get a Firefox add-on to change the user agent string. I don't know what else the gatekeeper has to determine if a request is from Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

IE6 support by MS is still not officially EOL. Mid of 2010 it will (half July if I recall correctly). Then we can all safely stop developing for IE6 and we have then also a strong enough argument for the customer.

Though, since IE8 came out I already don't do any pixel-precise *layout* fixes/alignments for IE6 anymore. Too **much** effort. I only fix the hasLayout/boxmodel bugs and some minor CSS inheritance issues which may affect *functionality*.

Answer (score 5):

"People should update the browser they use, right?"

Right, they should.  But they don't.

Comment: and sometimes - see "Corporations" reply - they simply can't.

Answer (score 3):

Its got nothing to do with how old the browser is, we still develop for it because the user useage (From Analytics) ranges from **30-40%**. So to stop using it would be like saying "dont buy our products" to 30-40% of potential clients.*Hardly a good move.*

Its not that hard to develop for IE6 and make a site work, it just takes a bit of extra time. I've actually picked up contracts from companies who have been to development houses and have been told we dont test IE6.

> When customers stop using i'll stop
>   developing, and they will only stop
>   using when i stop developing which will only happen when they stop using....etc etc

I also look at it like taking a 10 year old car into the petrol station and them saying "Sorry, your car's too old for this fuel" - Yes they offer new fuels, but still support the old, much the same in web-dev.

Comment: A more accurate analogy might be: 30-40% of the customers at your station routinely show up with cars that require one whole side of the body to be disassembled in order to access the fuel tank. You are required to serve these customers, of course, but while you are stuck doing so, all of the newer models (e.g. the Toyota CSS3, the Honda HTML5) are zooming past you to find another station.

Comment: Not true, infact we've just finished a really modern, heavy javascript website which runs in ie6 (Might be a bit slower than the newer models) but sure it runs. Does it really take that much time? I dont like IE6 anymore than the next guy but my sites work in it, its not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

Big companies developed web apps that run strictly on IE6. So rather than spend millions to update these apps, they would rather just keep on trucking with a non updated browser.

That's what I've always heard.

Comment: And it's a truth in many cases. It's just a lot of bureaucracy from people who don't really understand this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Our main reason is because the customers demand that we support it. The customer is always right... right? Also, I've seen IT departments still using IE6 because they rely on older apps that work with IE6.

Not to say that IE6 will stick forever, most places are **slowly** upgrading. Real IT people use firefox anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Also, i'm pretty sure my grandma has no idea that she even uses IE6, much less needs to upgrade for the sake of web standards and keeping up with the times. i'm also guessing that my grandma isnt alone in this.

Not that she shouldnt update, i just know that if any updating were to happen it would either have to be insanely simple or i would have to do it for her.

Comment: Bad excuse. Grandma can easily update her computer or have it done for her. Businesses are a different matter. They're stuck.

Comment: just trying to say that i think there's a sizeable user base that doesnt even care what browser they're using.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the big corporate clients we develop software for all run IE6 as their company browser. They simply refuse to reinvest the money in developing for another browser platform when their current software is working fine. (If it ain't broke, don't fix it philosophy)

I don't like it, but the client is king...

G

Answer (score 1):

IE6 when it came out looong back was a good piece of technology. It had left such great impressions that it became the default on windows systems.

Many non-tech folks are still uncomfortable moving out of IE6. Though, the time has come with MS themselves pushing to move IE6 out of the market.

Hopefully, in coming year or so, we wouldn't have to write for IE6 specifically..

Still in general, it would help a great deal if all browsers agreed to one particular standard of html/css/js atleast.

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer: because of statistics. About 20% of people visiting our webpages are still using IE6. Our policy is to optimize our webpages for browsers that have at least 5% share in our metrics.

Our company will mass-migrate to Firefox very soon, so at least our intranet webbies will be optimized just for it :)

We are currently developing an intranet tool and we still require to optimize it for IE6, even if whole company will be using Firefox in few months. Now, how stupid is that? :p

Answer (score 0):

Because many have customers who would never update their browsers. As to why, it is a much better question than this one.

Comment: Doesn't IE6 let you know there is an update available? Why wouldn't people just click, "OK, download it for me."

Comment: @Papucciono1- Corporations control their updates, users don't just click 'update' on their machine, that would cause havoc for the sys admins.

Answer (score 0):

Large corporate base of users who still have it installed because it works with legacy software they run...

Answer (score 0):

I develop sites for the general public.  If 15% of them are still using IE6, I have to decide whether my site not working is enough to get them to upgrade their browser, or if they'll just not use my site.

I usually decide that the user won't upgrade, so I support IE6.

Some people are not in control of their browser version, and cannot upgrade it.  For example, locked down PCs at work.

Answer (score 0):

I try to make our web applications simple, testing on IE7, and hope that it still works on IE6. Sometimes I get complaints from our customers (which is both end user and provider, since it is internal intranet application) that it does not work on IE6 and I tear my hair off and try to fix it as best I can. I also ask our on site support person why they don't upgrade, but I get no good answer other than "company policy". Even though we know it's a bad policy...

Answer (score 0):

We have to. The client want to be all browser compatible. For myself, I never and I will never develop a website for IE6.

Answer (score 0):

**You're right. People should upgrade their browser.**

But experience and time tells us that just because the users *should* do something, that doesn't necessarily mean they *are* going to do something.

We still need to cater to these people and this browser because it is still so widely used - because it is necessary to get our products out there to the users, no matter what browser they're using.

**Ultimately, though - it's your decision.**